# Angularjs always filter from initial data in a custom filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to use a custom filter to filter data based on search word. A scope attribute which gets populated in the contoller scope below:

```
naApp.controller('naCareNewTicketCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'careservice', 'ptypesFilter',function($scope, $http, $window,  ptypesFilter) {
$scope.problemtypes = [{
    "name": "Fruit",
    "subtypes": [{
        "name": "Seeded",
        "subsubtypes": [{
            "name": "Apple"
        }, {
            "name": "Oranges"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Acidic",
        "subsubtypes": [{
            "name": "Lemon"
        }, {
            "name": "Orange"
        }]
    }]
}];

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="problem in problemtypes | ptypes:search">
   <ul>
       <li ng-if="problem.subtypes && problem.subtypes.length>0">{{problem.name}}</li>
       <li class="main-probs ellipsify no-child" ng-if="!(problem.subtypes && problem.subtypes.length>0)">{{problem.name}}</li>
          <ul ng-repeat="subproblem in problem.subtypes">
             <li ng-if="subproblem.subsubtypes && subproblem.subsubtypes.length>0">{{subproblem.name}}</li>
             <li class="sub-probs ellipsify no-child" ng-if="!(subproblem.subsubtypes && subproblem.subsubtypes.length>0)">{{subproblem.name}}</li>
             <li class="sub-sub-probs ellipsify no-child" ng-repeat="subsubproblem in subproblem.subsubtypes" ng-click="selectproblem(problem, subproblem, subsubproblem )">{{subsubproblem.name}}</li>
           </ul>
   </ul>
</div>
```

custom filter code:

```
naApp.filter('ptypesFilter', function() {
  return function(items, searchText) {
    if(searchText === undefined || searchText.length === 0){
      return items;
    } else {
      var filteredItems = [];
      for(var t = 0; t < items.length; t++){
        var type = items[t];
      // if item.name sub string matches then show entire item
      var pName = type.name;
      if(pName.indexOf(searchText) === 0){
        filteredItems.push(type);
      } else {
        // check for sub types
        if(type.subtypes !== undefined) {
          var subtypes = [];
          for(var st = 0; st < type.subtypes.length; st++){
            var stype = type.subtypes[st];
            var sPName = stype.name;
            if(sPName.indexOf(searchText) === 0) {
              subtypes.push(stype);
            } else {
              if(stype.subsubtypes !== undefined){
                var subsubtypes = [];
                for(var sst = 0; sst < stype.subsubtypes.length; sst++){
                  var sstype = stype.subsubtypes[sst];
                  var ssPName = sstype.name;
                  if(ssPName.indexOf(searchText) === 0){
                    subsubtypes.push(sstype);
                  }
                }
                if(subsubtypes.length > 0){
                  stype.subsubtypes = subsubtypes;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          if(subtypes.length > 0){
            type.subtypes = subtypes;
          }
        }
        if(type.subtypes !== undefined && type.subtypes.length > 0){
          filteredItems.push(type);
        }
      }
    };
    }
    return filteredItems;
  };
});
```

As on filtering I put only matching subtypes/subsubtypes when the name attribute of the subtypes/subsubtypes match the text typed in an array and assign it to the parent back. (I need to show the hierarchy of the matching types) When i remove all the text how can I get the original object back so that I have unfiltered intial set to populate. I tried doing a $.extend on the object before filtering but that gives me infdig error.

Comment: At first, the variable `$scope.types` should be named `$scope.problemtypes` and your filter should be called that way: `<div ng-repeat="problem in problemtypes | ptypesFilter:search">`

Answer (score 0):

In the filter try using `angular.copy()`

```
// make array copy 
var itemsCopy = angular.copy(items);

var filteredItems = [];
// only modify copy
for(var t = 0; t < itemsCopy .length; t++){
      var type = itemsCopy[t];
  ..........
```

Then if you modify any of those objects you aren't affecting the originals